# Add 1 to the max. number of rows

Tags: sql

I am trying to insert values in a table by selecting values from another table, I give every value a unique id so I chose to give them row numbers but on updating the other table I don't want all the values to be selected again ,to have more performance, so I want to add the new values only. so each Time I add new Employee I have to add all employees again in the other table. so what can I do to get the max number of rows and add 1 to them to get a new unique id for this new employee ?

```
Select    1 , -- FormNo - smallint
      334 , -- FieldNo - smallint
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MAX(EmpId)+1) , -- FieldItemNo - smallint
      CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId)+'-'+profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40)) , -- FieldItemValue - nvarchar(40)
      CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) , -- FieldItemAValue - nvarchar(40)
      CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId)+'-'+profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40))  -- FieldItemFValue - nvarchar(40)
     FROM dbo.EmpAssignment 
    INNER JOIN profile ON Profile.ProfileId = EmpAssignment.EmpId 
    WHERE EmpAssignment.Status=1 AND
     (CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) NOT IN (SELECT FieldItemAValue FROM dbo.UserFieldsItems WHERE FieldNo = 334))
     GROUP BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY MAX(EmpId) + 1 ) ,
              CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId) + '-' + profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40)) ,
              CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) ,
              CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId) + '-' + profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40))
              ORDER BY CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId)+'-'+profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40))
```

This code can get me the new employee :

```
Select    1 , -- FormNo - smallint
      334 , -- FieldNo - smallint
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpId) , -- FieldItemNo - smallint
      CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId)+'-'+profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40)) , -- FieldItemValue - nvarchar(40)
     CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) , -- FieldItemAValue - nvarchar(40)
      CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId)+'-'+profile.name) AS NVARCHAR(40))  -- FieldItemFValue - nvarchar(40)
     FROM dbo.EmpAssignment 
    INNER JOIN profile ON Profile.ProfileId = EmpAssignment.EmpId 
    WHERE EmpAssignment.Status=1
    AND (CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) NOT IN (SELECT FieldItemAValue FROM dbo.UserFieldsItems WHERE FormNo = 1 AND FieldNo = 334))
```

but the number of rows will be one so it will make a conflict with the first employee

Comment: What database is it? In postgresql you have the serial type which autoincrement. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html

Comment: I'd guess SQL Server. (Those dbo...)

Comment: Move all the CAST/LTRIM stuff into a derived table, do group by at top level.

Comment: Do you need a stable ID for the rows or does it matter?

Comment: This really looks and feels like a "view' to me and if so you can use row number: `CREATE VIEW [MyView] as
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY col1 ) AS id, col1, col2, col3
FROM (
    Select col1, col2, col3 From Table1 ) AS MyResults
GO`
`

Answer (score 0):

If its SQL Server then the unique_id as an identity, like identity(10000,1) so that the first value starts at 10000 then increments by 1 on every insert. Also don't select a value for the Unique_id while inserting it will be updated, automatically.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/identity-columns/

Comment: I am not selecting the unique id for them I need any style to create their own id for each of them even if I want to add a new one it will take the max. and add 1 to it or anything ... I have the type smallint I can enter anything I want .. using any technique !

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer I got from my supervisor, Hope it may helps somebody one day.

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.UserFieldsItems
    ( FormNo ,
      FieldNo ,
      FieldItemNo ,
      FieldItemValue ,
      FieldItemAValue ,
      FieldItemFValue 
    )
SELECT  1 , -- FormNo - smallint
    334 , -- FieldNo - smallint
    ( SELECT MAX(dbo.UserFieldsItems.FieldItemNo)FROM dbo.UserFieldsItems) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY EmpId ) , -- FieldItemNo - smallint
    CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId) + '-' + Profile.Name) AS NVARCHAR(40)) , -- FieldItemValue - nvarchar(40)
    CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) , -- FieldItemAValue - nvarchar(40)
    CAST(LTRIM(STR(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId) + '-' + Profile.Name) AS NVARCHAR(40))  -- FieldItemFValue - nvarchar(40)
FROM    dbo.EmpAssignment
    INNER JOIN Profile ON Profile.ProfileId = EmpAssignment.EmpId
WHERE   EmpAssignment.Status = 1
    AND ( CAST(dbo.EmpAssignment.EmployeeId AS NVARCHAR(40)) NOT IN (
          SELECT    FieldItemAValue
          FROM      dbo.UserFieldsItems
          WHERE     FormNo = 1
                    AND FieldNo = 334 ) );
```